# Getting Data (long data) from One Object?

Tags: java, object, linked-list, long-integer

I'm working on a project and I'm being forced to make a Linked List that holds objects. Linked lists, as in a data structure that holds things like strings or int values (like arrays, vectors)

In each object there are four types of data (string, double, int, long); but I am only interested in the long value.

TL;DR:
So I guess my question is: "How do I get one value (long) from one Object that holds different types of data"?

Comment: You don't need to guess your question itself. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
public class A {
    private int a;
    private String s;
    private double d;
    private long l;

    // have getters and setters for these 

        public int getA() {
            return a;
        }
        public void setA(int a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        public String getS() {
            return s;
        }
        public void setS(String s) {
            this.s = s;
        }
        public double getD() {
            return d;
        }
        public void setD(double d) {
            this.d = d;
        }
        public long getL() {
            return l;
        }
        public void setL(long l) {
            this.l = l;
        }

}
```

now suppose u have a LinkedList as

```
LinkedList<A> lla = new LinkedList<A>();
```

and u have added object of A as

```
A a = new A();
```

//initialise the state of a

```
a.setA(2);
a.setS("Hello");
a.setD(4);
a.setL(5l);
```

add it to linkedlist

```
lla.add(a);
```

u can get object of A anytime if u have the reference of LinkedList lla as

```
A aObj = lla.get(position); // position is the position of object a of A
```

then do

```
long lOfA = aObj.getL();
```

Comment: Sorry, I lost your explanation at this part:

"A aObj = lla.get(position); // position is the position of object a of A"

I also forgot to mention that the object is being created in a different public class, then the object is sent to a method that puts that object in one element(node, or spot) in the Linked List. 

Right now I'm actually trying to create an indexOf method that accepts a long value and looks for that long value in the linked lists (which of course, only holds objects) 

So my header for the indexOf is "public int indexOf(long value)"